# htaccess redirect GET /?param=str to example.com/somewhere

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect WordPress page to somewhere.

```
http://example.com/?na=s
```

to

```
http://example.com/somewhere/
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^na=s$
RewriteRule !^/$ http://example.com/somewhere/? [L,R=301]
```

Full file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^na=s$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://example.com/somewhere/? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I assume `Htacess` in the title was just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, your "redirect" needs to go at the start of your file, before the existing WordPress rewrites. The WP front controller catches all requests, so your redirect never gets processed.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^na=s$
> RewriteRule ^/$ http://example.com/somewhere/? [L,R=301]
> ```

However, you are are also using *negated* regex (that's what the `!` prefix does), so it will match when the query string is *not* `^na=s$`.

Also, in per-directory `.htaccess` files the directory prefix is removed from the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so `^/$` will never match. (Although you had `!^/$` in the snippet above the "Full file?)

Try the following, *before* your existing rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^na=s$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/somewhere/? [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache, since any (erroneous) 301s are cached hard by the browser. (Often easier to test with caching disabled and use 302s until you are sure it's working OK.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. l learn alot from you.